# Binomial probability majority question

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm working in a Binomial probability problem.

Here $p=0.25$, so $q=0.75$, $X=0,1,2,3,4,5$

The problem says what is the probability that the majority will accept; is it asking me to find $P(X=3)$ or $P(X\geq3)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $X = 3, X = 4, $ and $X = 5$ all mean more than half accept, then the problem is asking you to find $P(X \ge 3).$ That is, assuming that $p=0.25$ is the probability that each one of them accepts.